# Mageck-Vispr problem to visualize results

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the tool vispr in able to visualize the results of the mageck-vispr run. I have installed everything as explained on the website within a conda environment.

Unfortunately, when running the command

vispr server results/ESC-mle.vispr.yaml

I receive the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/sw/mambaforge/10/envs/mageck-vispr/bin/vispr", line 6, in 
from vispr.cli import main
File "/sw/mambaforge/10/envs/mageck-vispr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vispr/cli.py", line 28, in 
from vispr.server import app
File "/sw/mambaforge/10/envs/mageck-vispr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vispr/server.py", line 13, in 
from jinja2 import Markup
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (/sw/mambaforge/10/envs/mageck-vispr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/**init**.py)

I tried to create a new exclusive environment for Mageck.

Has anyone had the same problem and can suggest me a solution or good free alternatives tools??

thanks